# RSA signature forgery with e=41 and broken padding

Tags: cryptography, rsa

There is RSA signature check which has following properties:

- RSA modulus N which is 2048-bit
- RSA exponent equal 41 (0x29)
- Signature uses EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padding of SHA1 hash, however the decoder only compares 20 least significant bytes which are the SHA1 hash

This means that all but the 20 least significant bytes, after rising forged signature to 41st power modulo N, can be garbage.

I have checked following:

- [Bleichenbacher's RSA signature forgery based on implementation error](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/openpgp/current/msg00999.html) is not applicable here as it deals with most significant bytes (least significant bytes are garbage) and as I tested it cannot forge signature that would contain 20 bytes of arbitrary chosen prefix when e=41
- Yutaka Oiwa, Kazukuni Kobara, Hajime Watanabe: A New Variant for an Attack Against RSA Signature Verification Using Parameter Field - RSA modulus is too small for this method to be effective here. This is the attack that Intel used in [BERserk](http://www.intelsecurity.com/resources/wp-berserk-analysis-part-1.pdf)

Is there any computationally feasible algorithm that could be used to forge signature that verifier, which only checks the 20 least significant bytes, would accept?

Edit:
Is the [Poncho comment from another RSA attack question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26467/attack-for-rsa-1024-bit-with-low-public-exponent#comment61449_26478) feasible here? If so, how to implement:

x=MD5(Message) find a 128 bit number y with [image: y^3=x (mod 2^128)] (which will exist if x is odd, and can be found in 128 steps);

The changes in this case would be:

- 41 instead of 3
- SHA1 instead of MD5
- 180 instead of 128

Edit2:
I think the Poncho comments mentions exactly the same what is implemented in `forge_suffix_odd` presented in [BERserk Vulnerability part 1](http://www.intelsecurity.com/resources/wp-berserk-analysis-part-1.pdf).

This function however, as noted previously, gives too big values. Is the result of `forge_suffix_odd` the lowest possible number fullfilling the goal?

Edit3: forge_suffix_odd returns the lowest possible number fullfilling the goal.

Edit4: [Greg Martin answered my question at Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778579/how-do-i-find-the-smallest-positive-integer-a-for-which-an-equiv-x-pmod2) and provided very useful solution for SHA1 checksums whose least significant bits equal 0.

Comment: If they are for all practical purposes using a 20 byte hash then a birthday attack on such a hash should be perfectly feasible. What that can do for you with this particular protocol, I don't know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question. It would be more appropriate for crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohnColeman: Would the birthday attack implementation consist of modifing the message (this for example could be the last 4 hashed bytes, which are the creation time) and comparing resulting hash against a hash from a set of both genuine and few forged signatures? I have 6 genuine signatures.

Comment: Strongly related [crypto.SE question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35240/555). However that other question lacks a number of details added to the present question.